# Rails: how to bypass Uploader for CSV bulk uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, file-upload, carrierwave, image-uploading

I am working on a project where I want to import some listings through CSV uploads. The rails app allows people to do CRUD actions from the front end.

The Listing class is as follows:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base  
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

The uploader class is as follows:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base


  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
   storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end


  #Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [200, 200]
  end

end
```

But on the backend, I am trying to bypass the image uploading to fog when the image URL is already provided in the CSV file. I don't want to run an uploader for the image.

I am working on CSV uploading. Currently, the code looks like:

```
def self.import(file)       
        count = 0
        CSV.foreach(file, headers: true, encoding:'iso-8859-1:utf-8') do |row|


            data = {}

            row.to_hash.each do |k, v|
                key = MAP[k]
                data[key] = v
            end

            unless data[:vin] == nil


                listing =  Listing.find_by_vin(data[:vin]) || Listing.new

                #listing.attributes = (row.to_hash).merge(image: URI.parse(row['image'])) #         
                listing.title = "#{data[:year]} #{data[:make]} #{data[:model]}"


                unless data[:all_images] == nil



                    listing_images = data[:all_images].split(",")
                    i = 0

                    [:image, :imagefront, :imageback, :imageleft, :imageright, :frontinterior, :rearinterior].each do |image|               
                        unless listing_images.size < 1
                            data[image] = listing_images[i]                         
                            i += 1
                        end
                        p "hello"
                    end

                end


                data.delete(:all_images)


                p data
                listing.attributes = data


                if listing.valid?                   
                    if listing.save!
                        count = count+1
                    end                                 
                end


             end
        end

        return count
    end
```

When I am trying to set the image to a url it's giving me nil when saving the listing with data hash. However, the data Hash used in the function does have the :image attribute as seen below as a result of test and listing has :image attribute as well.
[image]

My main question is:
How can I bypass/override the uploader action in Listing creation and set the image url to the url string given in the csv file. Even if I am setting the url its not getting set and the listing is being saved with :image as nil.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem myself. Answering for those who may face similar problems.

I used open-uri for getting the image from the given url, and then assigned the result to the listing attribute images in a loop.

```
[:image, :imagefront, :imageback, :imageleft, :imageright, :frontinterior, :rearinterior].each do |image|               
    unless listing_images.size < 1
    data[image] = CsvUploading::picture_from_url(listing_images[i])
    i += 1
  end               
end
```

Separated the function picture_from_url in a module so I can use it again in other classes.

```
require "open-uri"

module CsvUploading

  def self.picture_from_url(url)
    open(url)
  end
end
```

P.S. This work on heroku as well. The problem now is that the CSV uploading is doing a lot of queries and heroku is giving an application error. I would have to use batch queries instead.